# Understanding how Ruby parses statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While working on the console, `Date.today -12.months` and `Date.today - 12.months` give different outputs, can someone explain how Ruby parses these 2 statements?

To be precises, the output of `Date.today -12.months` is the current date, whereas , `Date.today - 12.months` returns a year old timestamp, which is what I expected in the first case.

Comment: Ruby has no method `Fixnum#months` (or `Integer#months`). You need a Rails' tag.

Comment: Tip: use `-w` to enable warnings (works with both irb and ruby).

Answer (score 0):

`Date.today -12.months` is parsed as:

```
Date.today ((- 12).months)
```

`Date.today - 12.months` is parsed as:

```
Date.today - (12.months)
```

Comment: `Date.today -360` and `Date.today 360` both return a `Date` object representing today's date. Why is the former different than `Date.today - 360` (e.g., `5 - 2` and `5 -2` are the same) and why does the latter not raise an exception, as would, say, `222 360`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think the difference is that `Date.today()` accepts arguments, whereas e.g. `1` does not. Probably operator precedence kicks in -> `Date.today.-(360)` vs. `Date.today(-360)` .

Answer (score 0):

I am digging in the fog here, but taking awesome @sawa's answer, I would explain it like below. **Note that Date.today takes an start - argument (like most Date functions)**.

```
Date.today       # returns a date
Date.today(-12)   # accepts arguments: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today

Date.today.-(12) # implements '-' "operator"
```

The last statement should make the trick: If called like `Date.today -12` it is (see @sawas answer) dealt with like `Date.today(-12)`. If instead you give the `minus` a bit of space it will eat an argument, as in `Date.today - 12`, which equals `Date.today.-(12)`, which could also be written as `Date.today.- 12`.